# Testing if the matrix is a symmetric or skew-symmetric?

Tags: python

I'm doing my Laboratory exercise in Python.
i made the code but i don't know how will i make a test if the matrix is a symmetric or skew-symmetric. The problems are:
1. Make a test if the matrix is symmetric or skew-symmetric.
2. How will I use assertion to be sure that the matrix is a square matrix?
3. Can someone make a recheck to my codes?
Thanks!

```
def symmetric(X):
H = X.copy()
D = len(H)
F = len(H[0])
listx = []
listy = []   
for d in range(0,D):
    listx.append(0)
for f in range(0,F):
    listy.append(listx)
K = np.array(listy)
for i in range(0,D):
    for j in range(0,F):
        K[j][i] = H[i][j]
return K

def skewsymmetric(Y):
H = Y.copy()
D = len(H)
F = len(H[0])
listx = []
listy = []
R = -1
for d in range(0,D):
    listx.append(0)
for f in range(0,F):
    listy.append(listx)
K = np.array(listy)
for i in range(0,D):
    for j in range(0,F):
        K[j][i] = H[i][j]*R
return K

if __name__ == "__main__":
X = np.array([[20,120,200],[120,10,150],[200,150,30]])
Y = np.array([[0,1,-3],[-1,0,-2],[3,2,0]])
print "X =", X
print "Y =", Y
print "This is Symmetric matrix:", symmetric(X)
print "This is Skew-symmetric matrix:", skewsymmetric(Y)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a simple way to check if matrix is symmetric using numpy:

```
(arr.transpose() == arr).all()
```

If you need to check if it's skew-symmetric, then change the sign of the second "arr" in comparison:

```
(arr.transpose() == -arr).all()
```

Comment: I can't use transpose to my code. Because my lab exercise needs to use a "for loop" and "assert". So i need to stick with my code, and just need to change something. Also make the two methods in one.

Comment: I get "AttributeError: all not found". Am I missing an import or something?

Comment: I can't reproduce your error. Maybe there's an error in your imports?
Can you declare array without issues?